# After datepicker onchange function, send value to same php page with javascript/ajax call without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to populate a portion of PHP page in a div where results are retrieved from a Mysql DB after a datepicker calendar onchange function.
Every time I select a date from calendar, I would see the hours available.
My concept is:
1. I choose a date
2. a div with the hours table appear with availability
3. select a radio button of the disponible hour, then send my choose to the db.

The problem is at point 2.

This is the javascript code inside the page, just before the head close

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if(sessionStorage.getItem("homecal") === null || sessionStorage.getItem("prenotacal") === null) {
        $('#datasel').html('Seleziona la data della visita dal calendario.');
        $('#prenota-ora').hide();
    }

    if(sessionStorage.getItem("homecal") !== null) {
        $('#datasel').html('Hai selezionato il giorno ' + sessionStorage.getItem("homecal"));
        $('#giornosel').val(sessionStorage.getItem("homedate")); //scrive la data nell'input hidden
        $('#prenota-ora').show();
    }

    if(sessionStorage.getItem("prenotacal") !== null) {
        $('#datasel').html('Hai selezionato il giorno ' + sessionStorage.getItem("prenotacal"));
        $('#prenota-ora').show();
    }


    var homedate    = sessionStorage.getItem("homedate");

    var days        = new Date(homedate);
    var NumDays     = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
    var dayNum  = NumDays[days.getDay()];

    if(homedate !== null && dayNum == '1' || dayNum == '3' || dayNum == '5') { //lunedi e mercoledi e venerdi
        $('#orari-mattina').hide();
        $('#orari-pomeriggio').fadeIn('1000');
        $('#avanti').hide();
        }
    if(homedate !== null && dayNum == '2' || dayNum == '4') { //martedi e giovedi
        $('#orari-mattina').fadeIn('1000');
        $('#orari-pomeriggio').fadeIn('2000');
        $('#avanti').hide();
        }

    var anno        = new Date().getFullYear();

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        language: "it",
        keyboardNavigation: false,
        forceParse: false,
        daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,1,4,6",
        todayHighlight: true,
        startDate: "-0m",
        immediateUpdates: true,
        toggleActive:true,
        datesDisabled: ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-07', '2019-01-09', '2019-01-11', '2019-01-12', '2019-01-13', 'anno-01-01', 'anno-01-02', 'anno-01-03', 'anno-01-04', 'anno-01-05','anno-01-06','anno-01-07', 'anno-01-09', 'anno-01-11', 'anno-01-12', 'anno-01-13', 'anno-04-02', 'anno-04-25', 'anno-04-30', 'anno-05-01', 'anno-06-02', 'anno-06-08', 'anno-06-11', 'anno-08-01', 'anno-08-02', 'anno-08-03', 'anno-08-04', 'anno-08-05', 'anno-08-06', 'anno-08-07', 'anno-08-08', 'anno-08-09', 'anno-08-10', 'anno-08-11', 'anno-08-12',  'anno-08-13', 'anno-08-14', 'anno-08-15', 'anno-08-16', 'anno-08-17', 'anno-08-18', 'anno-08-19', 'anno-08-20', 'anno-08-21', 'anno-08-22', 'anno-08-23', 'anno-08-24', 'anno-08-25', 'anno-08-26', 'anno-08-27', 'anno-08-28', 'anno-08-29', 'anno-08-30', 'anno-08-31', 'anno-11-01', 'anno-12-07', 'anno-12-08', 'anno-12-09', 'anno-12-24', 'anno-12-25', 'anno-12-26', 'anno-12-27', 'anno-12-29', 'anno-12-30', 'anno-12-31', ]

     }).on('changeDate', function() {

    $('#prenota-ora').show();
    $('#orari-mattina').hide();
    $('#orari-pomeriggio').hide();
    $('#avanti'). hide();
    $('input[name="orario"]').prop('checked', false); //resetta orario
    $('#orario').val(""); //resetta orario

    sessionStorage.removeItem("homecal");
    sessionStorage.removeItem("homedate");
    sessionStorage.removeItem("orarioselezionato");
    $('#orariosel').html(""); //resetta orario


    sessionStorage.setItem("prenotadate", $('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate'));   // CREA SESSIONE DEL GIORNO HOME FORMATO DATE

    var values = sessionStorage.getItem("prenotadate");

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }

     var PageToSendTo = "prenotazione/prenota.php?";
     var MyVariable = sessionStorage.getItem("prenotadate");
     var VariablePlaceholder = "giornosel=";
     var UrlToSend = PageToSendTo + VariablePlaceholder + MyVariable;

     xmlhttp.open("GET", UrlToSend, true);
     xmlhttp.send();

          var days      = new Date($('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate'));
          var NumDays   = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
          var dayNum    = NumDays[days.getDay()];

          if(dayNum == '1' || dayNum == '3' || dayNum == '5') { //lunedi e mercoledi e venerdi
          $('#orari-pomeriggio').fadeIn('1000');
          }
          if(dayNum == '2' || dayNum == '4') { //martedi e giovedi
          $('#orari-mattina').fadeIn('1000');
          $('#orari-pomeriggio').fadeIn('2000');
          }

    // Test with ajax method with different approaches
    //$.ajax({ // SEND VALUE TO PHP
    //  type:"GET",
    //  url: "prenotazione/prenota.php",
    //    url: "index.php?a=prenotazione-online&go=prenota",
    //  data:{giornosel:values},
    //    data: 'data='+JSON.stringify({giornosel:values}),
    //  dataType:"text",
    //  async: false,
    //  headers: {
          //     'Accept': '*/*',
          //     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
          //     'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' //Client 
    //          'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' //Client 
    //  },
    //  success: function(data){
    //  console.log(data);
    //      var days        = new Date($('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate'));
    //        var NumDays   = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
    //        var dayNum    = NumDays[days.getDay()];

    //       if(dayNum == '1' || dayNum == '3' || dayNum == '5') { //lunedi e mercoledi e venerdi
    //    $('#orari-pomeriggio').fadeIn('1000');
    //    }
    //    if(dayNum == '2' || dayNum == '4') { //martedi e giovedi
    //    $('#orari-mattina').fadeIn('1000');
    //    $('#orari-pomeriggio').fadeIn('2000');
    //    }
    //  return true;
    //  },
    //  complete: function() {},
    //  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //  console.log('ajax loading error...');
    //  return false;
    //  }
    //}); //END AJAX


    var monthNames = ["Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre",  "Novembre", "Dicembre"];

    var d               = new Date(sessionStorage.getItem('prenotadate'));
    var day                 = d.getDate();
    var monthIndex      = d.getMonth();
    var year                = d.getFullYear();
    var prenotacal  = day + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year;

    $('#datasel').html('Hai selezionato il giorno ' + prenotacal);

    sessionStorage.setItem("prenotacal", prenotacal);   // CREA SESSIONE DEL GIORNO HOME FORMATO CALENDARIO 

    }); //END ONCHANGE

    $('input:radio[name=orario]').change(function() {

    var orario = $('input:radio[name=orario]:checked').attr('id');
    $('#orario').val(orario);

    var ore     = orario.substr(0,2);
    var min     = orario.substr(2,4);

    var orarioselezionato   = ore + ':' + min;

    sessionStorage.setItem("orarioselezionato", orarioselezionato); // crea sessione formato ora
    sessionStorage.setItem("orario", orario); // crea sessione formato tabella

    if(sessionStorage.getItem("orarioselezionato") === null) {}
    else {
    $('#orariosel').html(', alle ore ' + sessionStorage.getItem("orarioselezionato"));
    }

    if(sessionStorage.getItem("orarioselezionato") !== null && (sessionStorage.getItem("prenotadate") !== null || sessionStorage.getItem("homedate") !== null)) {
    $('#avanti').show();
    } else {}

    }); // END CHANGE FUNCTION
    }); // END READY FUNCTION
```

I tried lot of times different solutions to send data to php page as ajax call GET/POST method also with JSON datatype but it run sometimes correctly only on firebug panel, not on web page.

The portion of PHP that manage the hours is:

```
<?php
     switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
     case 'POST':
     post_handler();
     break;

     case 'GET':
     get_handler();
     break;

     default:
     other_handler();
     break;
     }

     function post_handler() {
 //    $raw_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
 //    $req_body = json_decode($raw_data, TRUE);
 //    $giornosel = call_user_func($req_body['function'], $req_body['giornosel']);
       $giornosel  = $_POST['giornosel'];
       echo"(POST method) "; //only for testing
       echo"$giornosel"; //only for testing
      }

     function get_handler() {
     $giornosel  = $_GET['giornosel'];
     echo"(GET method) "; //only for testing
     echo"$giornosel"; //only for testing
     }

    function other_handler() {
    $giornosel  = $_REQUEST['giornosel'];
    echo"REQUEST"; //only for testing
    echo"$giornosel"; //only for testing
    }

// This first query populate the div of the enabled hour cells   
    $query = DB_Query("SELECT * FROM $table21n WHERE enabled = '1' AND fascia ='1'  ORDER BY orario ASC");

    while ($result = DB_Get_Results($query))
    {

    $div_id = $result[orario];

// this second query check the hours in DB that are available or not with a simple count. If available, the radio button is displayed, otherwise not.
    $count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM $table20n WHERE orario = '$div_id' AND giorno = '$giornosel' ");
    $res_count = mysql_fetch_row($count);
    $totale = $res_count[0];

    if($totale >= $valore) {
    $disabled = invisible; // some css class
    $bgcolor = BGoccupato;
    }
    else {
         $disabled = '';
         $bgcolor = 'BGlibero';
         }

    $conto = ($valore-$totale);

    echo"<div id='$div_id' class='centopercento $bgcolor' >";

    $ore = substr($div_id, 0,2);
    $min =substr($div_id, 2,4);

    echo"$ore:$min</br>";

    echo"<input class='$disabled radiorario' type='radio' value='$div_id' name='orario' id='$div_id'>";
    echo"</div>";
    }

?>
```

I had a trouble about headers so I tried also to change headers (accept, content-type, data-type) but the result is the same.
The value is sent correctly both on GET and POST method as I can see on the firebug panel, the parameter pair is correct, the response in the payload is correct but doesn't run on the web page.

In conclusion I think that the date selected by the calendar is sent correctly.
But I'm not sure what happens next. the PHP page read the value? How the sent value can be read correctly and used to update the page? Can I send a request via javascript or ajax to the same page?

This is the web page where I'm working [test](https://www.rinnovopatenticitylife.it/prenotazione-online/prenota.html)

Any suggestion is warmly appreciate! Thank you!

**UPDATE 11/01/2019**

This is the full code of the prenota.php page updated following the below suggestion

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="it">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>prenota</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.00, minimum-scale = 0.25, maximum-scale = 2.20">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
OMITTED
-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

if(sessionStorage.getItem("homecal") === null || sessionStorage.getItem("prenotacal") === null) {
    $('#datasel').html('Seleziona la data della visita dal calendario.');
    $('#prenota-ora').hide();
}

if(sessionStorage.getItem("homecal") !== null) {
    $('#datasel').html('Hai selezionato il giorno ' + sessionStorage.getItem("homecal"));
    $('#giornosel').val(sessionStorage.getItem("homedate")); //scrive la data nell'input hidden
    $('#prenota-ora').show();
}

if(sessionStorage.getItem("prenotacal") !== null) {
    $('#datasel').html('Hai selezionato il giorno ' + sessionStorage.getItem("prenotacal"));
    $('#prenota-ora').show();
}

var homedate    = sessionStorage.getItem("homedate");

var days        = new Date(homedate);
var NumDays     = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
var dayNum  = NumDays[days.getDay()];

if(homedate !== null && dayNum == '1' || dayNum == '3' || dayNum == '5') { //lunedi e mercoledi e venerdi
    $('#orari-mattina').hide();
    $('#orari-pomeriggio').fadeIn('1000');
    $('#avanti').hide();
    }
if(homedate !== null && dayNum == '2' || dayNum == '4') { //martedi e giovedi
    $('#orari-mattina').fadeIn('1000');
    $('#orari-pomeriggio').fadeIn('2000');
    $('#avanti').hide();
    }

var anno        = new Date().getFullYear();

$('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    language: "it",
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    forceParse: false,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,1,4,6",
    todayHighlight: true,
    startDate: "-0m",
    immediateUpdates: true,
    toggleActive:true,
    datesDisabled: ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-06', '2019-01-07', '2019-01-09', '2019-01-11', '2019-01-12', '2019-01-13', 'anno-01-01', 'anno-01-02', 'anno-01-03', 'anno-01-04', 'anno-01-05','anno-01-06','anno-01-07', 'anno-01-09', 'anno-01-11', 'anno-01-12', 'anno-01-13', 'anno-04-02', 'anno-04-25', 'anno-04-30', 'anno-05-01', 'anno-06-02', 'anno-06-08', 'anno-06-11', 'anno-08-01', 'anno-08-02', 'anno-08-03', 'anno-08-04', 'anno-08-05', 'anno-08-06', 'anno-08-07', 'anno-08-08', 'anno-08-09', 'anno-08-10', 'anno-08-11', 'anno-08-12',  'anno-08-13', 'anno-08-14', 'anno-08-15', 'anno-08-16', 'anno-08-17', 'anno-08-18', 'anno-08-19', 'anno-08-20', 'anno-08-21', 'anno-08-22', 'anno-08-23', 'anno-08-24', 'anno-08-25', 'anno-08-26', 'anno-08-27', 'anno-08-28', 'anno-08-29', 'anno-08-30', 'anno-08-31', 'anno-11-01', 'anno-12-07', 'anno-12-08', 'anno-12-09', 'anno-12-24', 'anno-12-25', 'anno-12-26', 'anno-12-27', 'anno-12-29', 'anno-12-30', 'anno-12-31', ]

 }).on('changeDate', function() {

$('#prenota-ora').show();
$('#orari-mattina').hide();
$('#orari-pomeriggio').hide();
$('#avanti'). hide();
$('input[name="orario"]').prop('checked', false); //resetta orario
$('#orario').val(""); //resetta orario

sessionStorage.removeItem("homecal");
sessionStorage.removeItem("homedate");
sessionStorage.removeItem("orarioselezionato");
$('#orariosel').html(""); //resetta orario

sessionStorage.setItem("prenotadate", $('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate'));   // CREA SESSIONE DEL GIORNO HOME FORMATO DATE

var values = sessionStorage.getItem("prenotadate");

          var days      = new Date($('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate'));
      var NumDays   = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
      var dayNum    = NumDays[days.getDay()];

      if(dayNum == '1' || dayNum == '3' || dayNum == '5') { //lunedi e mercoledi e venerdi
      $('#orari-pomeriggio').fadeIn('1000');
      }
      if(dayNum == '2' || dayNum == '4') { //martedi e giovedi
//    $('#orari-mattina').fadeIn('1000');
      $('#orari-pomeriggio').fadeIn('2000');
      }

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "prenotazione/prenota.php",
    data: { giornosel:values },
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data.elememts.length){
            $.each(data.elements, function(i, el){
                var myEl = $("<" + el.tag + ">", el.attr);
                if(el.content != undefined){
                    myEl.html(el.content);
                }
                if(el.appendTo != undefined){
                myEl.appendTo(el.appendTo);
                } else {
                myEl.appendTo($('#orari'));
                }
            });
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Ajax Error: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});


var monthNames = ["Gennaio", "Febbraio", "Marzo", "Aprile", "Maggio", "Giugno", "Luglio", "Agosto", "Settembre", "Ottobre",  "Novembre", "Dicembre"];

var d               = new Date(sessionStorage.getItem('prenotadate'));
var day                 = d.getDate();
var monthIndex      = d.getMonth();
var year                = d.getFullYear();
var prenotacal  = day + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year;

$('#datasel').html('Hai selezionato il giorno ' + prenotacal);

sessionStorage.setItem("prenotacal", prenotacal);   // CREA SESSIONE DEL GIORNO HOME FORMATO CALENDARIO 

}); //END ONCHANGE

$('input:radio[name=orario]').change(function() {

var orario = $('input:radio[name=orario]:checked').attr('id');
$('#orario').val(orario);

var ore     = orario.substr(0,2);
var min     = orario.substr(2,4);

var orarioselezionato   = ore + ':' + min;

sessionStorage.setItem("orarioselezionato", orarioselezionato); // crea sessione formato ora
sessionStorage.setItem("orario", orario); // crea sessione formato tabella

if(sessionStorage.getItem("orarioselezionato") === null) {}
else {
$('#orariosel').html(', alle ore ' + sessionStorage.getItem("orarioselezionato"));
}

if(sessionStorage.getItem("orarioselezionato") !== null && (sessionStorage.getItem("prenotadate") !== null || sessionStorage.getItem("homedate") !== null)) {
$('#avanti').show();
} else {}

}); // END CHANGE FUNCTION
}); // END READY FUNCTION
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php?a=prenotazione-online&go=compila-dati" method=post>
<div id="PageDiv">
    <div id="prenota"><div id="prenota-selezione" class="text-center"><p class="f-fp f-lp"><span class="occhiello"><strong><span class="COL-blu">     <span id='datasel'></span><span id='orariosel'></span>  </span></strong></span></p>
        </div>
        <div id="prenota-giorno" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4"><div id="prenota-giorno-title" class="uppercase"><h2 class="f-fp f-lp"><span class="COL-blu">1° - seleziona il giorno</span></h2>
            </div>
            <div id="datepicker"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="prenota-ora" class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 prenota-ora"><div id="prenota-ora-title" class="uppercase"><h2 class="f-fp f-lp"><span class="COL-blu">2° - seleziona l'orario <?php
switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    case 'POST':
        post_handler();
        break;
    case 'GET':
        get_handler();
        break;
    default:
        other_handler();
        break;
}

$handler = array();
function post_handler() {
    $giornosel  = $_POST['giornosel'];
    $handler['method'] = "post";
    $handler['query'] = $giornosel;
}
function get_handler() {
    $giornosel  = $_GET['giornosel'];
    $handler['method'] = "get";
    $handler['query'] = $giornosel;
}
function other_handler() {
    $giornosel  = $_REQUEST['giornosel'];
    $handler['method'] = "request";
    $handler['query'] = $giornosel;
}
$data = array('handler' => $handler);

?> </span></h2>
            </div>
            <div id="orari"><div id="orari-mattina"><div id="titolo-mattina" class="uppercase col-xs-12 col-md-12"><h3 class="style2 f-fp f-lp">mattino</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div id="content-mattina"><p class="f-fp"><?php
$query = DB_Query("SELECT * FROM $table21n WHERE enabled = '1' AND fascia ='1'  ORDER BY orario ASC");
while ($result = DB_Get_Results($query))
{
$div_id = $result[orario];

$data['elements'] = array();

?></p>
                        <div id="ora-<?php echo"$div_id";?>" class="cella-orario col-xs-4 col-md-1 text-center"><p class="f-fp f-lp"><span id="oramattina"><?php
$count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM $table20n WHERE orario = '$div_id' AND giorno = '$giornosel' ");
$res_count = mysql_fetch_row($count);
$totale = $res_count[0];


//    echo"$div_id</br>"; // only for test
//    echo"$totale</br>"; // only for test
//    echo"$valore"; // only for test

if($totale >= $valore) {
    $disabled = invisible;
    $bgcolor = BGoccupato;
}
else {
    $disabled = '';
    $bgcolor = BGlibero;
}
    $ore = substr($div_id, 0,2);
    $min = substr($div_id, 2,4);

array_push($data['elements'], array(
        "tag" => 'div',
        "attr" => array(
            "id" => $div_id,
            "class" => "centopercento $bgcolor"
        ),
        "content" => "$ore:$min"
    ));
array_push($data['elements'], array(
        "tag" => 'input',
        "attr" => array(
            "type" => 'radio',
            "id" => $div_id,
            "class" => "$disabled radiorario",
        "value" => $div_id,
        "name" => 'orario'
        ),
       "appendTo" => '#' . $div_id
    ));
?></span></p>
                        </div>
                        <p class="f-lp"><?php
json_encode($data);

}
?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="orari-pomeriggio"><div id="titolo-pomeriggio" class="uppercase col-xs-12 col-md-12"><h3 class="style2 f-fp f-lp">pomeriggio</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div id="content-pomeriggio"><p class="f-fp"><?php
$query = DB_Query("SELECT * FROM $table21n WHERE enabled = '1' AND fascia ='2'  ORDER BY orario ASC");
while ($result = DB_Get_Results($query))
{
$div_id = $result[orario];

$data['elements'] = array();

?></p>
                        <div id="ora-<?php echo"$div_id";?>" class="cella-orario col-xs-4 col-md-2 text-center"><p class="f-fp f-lp"><span id="orapomeriggio"><?php
$count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM $table20n WHERE orario = '$div_id' AND giorno = '$giornosel' ");
$res_count = mysql_fetch_row($count);
$totale = $res_count[0];


//    echo"$div_id</br>"; // only for test
//    echo"$totale</br>"; // only for test
//    echo"$valore"; // only for test

if($totale >= $valore) {
    $disabled = invisible;
    $bgcolor = BGoccupato;
}
else {
    $disabled = '';
    $bgcolor = BGlibero;
}
    $ore = substr($div_id, 0,2);
    $min = substr($div_id, 2,4);

array_push($data['elements'], array(
        "tag" => 'div',
        "attr" => array(
            "id" => $div_id,
            "class" => "centopercento $bgcolor"
        ),
        "content" => "$ore:$min"
    ));
array_push($data['elements'], array(
        "tag" => 'input',
        "attr" => array(
            "type" => 'radio',
            "id" => $div_id,
            "class" => "$disabled radiorario",
        "value" => $div_id,
        "name" => 'orario'
        ),
       "appendTo" => '#' . $div_id
    ));
?></span></p>
                        </div>
                        <p class="f-lp"><?php
json_encode($data);

}
?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="avanti" class="text-center"><p class="f-fp f-lp">Se vuoi confermare clicca su <input id="avanti-button" type=submit name="invia" value="Prosegui" class="btn btn-yellow"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The echo of the `json_encode($data);` is now well structured but doesn't format well the html of that portion of page.

The doubt is: the array structure replace the html structure (divs etc..) or must be added as a hidden structure only to send JSON values?

Another one of my doubts is if this page can call itself via ajax call.

**Other update**

After the ajax call my date value (i.e. 2019-01-18) is sent with:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "prenotazione/dataencode.php",
    data: { giornosel:values },
    dataType:"json",
    contentType:"application/json",
    success: function(data){            
        console.log(data);
        if(data.elements.length){
            $.each(data.elements, function(i, el){
                var myEl = $("<" + el.tag + ">", el.attr);
                if(el.content != undefined){
                    myEl.html(el.content);
                }
                if(el.appendTo != undefined){
                    myEl.appendTo(el.appendTo);
                } else {
                    myEl.appendTo($('#prenota-ora'));
                }
            });
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Ajax Error: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

to a `dataencode.php` file:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");

$giornosel  = $_REQUEST['giornosel'];

$input = array("giorno" => $giornosel);

echo json_encode($input);

$encoded_array = json_encode($input);
file_put_contents("values.json", $encoded_array);

?>
```

that convert the value in a JSON object, well formatted and echoed like

```
{"giorno":"2019-01-18"}
```

on the firebug console panel, and write the value in a values.json file.

Then the datadecode.php file:

```
<?php
$url = "prenotazione/values.json";
$input = file_get_contents($url);
if(!isset($input))
    {
    echo"error";
    }
else {
    $result = json_decode($input, true);

    $giornosel = $result[giorno];

   echo"$giornosel";
    }
?>
```

decode the value to a php string.

This file is included with an `include('prenotazione/datadecode.php');` on the main page `prenota.php`.

Now I would to "update" or "load" or "refresh" only a div `#prenota-ora` where the php query populate the page

```
$count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM $table20n WHERE orario = '$div_id' AND giorno = '$giornosel' ");
$res_count = mysql_fetch_row($count);
$totale = $res_count[0];


if($totale >= $valore) {
$disabled = invisible;
$bgcolor = BGoccupato;
}
else {
$disabled = '';
$bgcolor = 'BGlibero';
}
```

I tried to load the div with `$("#prenota-ora").load();` after success function() in the ajax call but without success. How can I do?

Comment: Your MySQL query is vulnerable to SQL Injection. I would first advise investigating this and addressing that. Second I would check the browser console for any alerts or error. Next I would review the Network section of your Web Developer portion of your browser. You should be able to view the HTTP data that is sent and received. This will help you identify what is happening.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what do you mean about "query is vulnerable to SQL injection". There was an alert on the  browser console. The value of  this row was set to false:  `xmlhttp.open("GET", UrlToSend, false);`. Now is true. when send a call from the calendar, the network section it seems ok: headers, query string is well formatted (name:value) and the preview response show me the echoed date but not what the sql query could be after the call.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: I would also suggest testing your GET by entering the page in your browser manually: `prenotazione/prenota.php?giornosel=2019-01-10` and see what the response is.

Comment: It also looks like this is part of a Drupal script, is that the case?

Comment: @Twisty Thanks for the php manual. About your second answer, nothing happens, except the echoed date, because the Mysql connection file is in the index page. The `prenota.php` page is included on the index page with a switch method.

Comment: @Twisty No, I don't use any CMS. I write by myself all the code

Comment: When I test the script on your page, it navigated to https://www.rinnovopatenticitylife.it/prenotazione/prenota.php?giornosel=2019-01-18 and I am getting a giant payload of HTML in response. You will want to consider how this script works. I would advise sending back just JSON data that the Script can use to build the new content instead of sending HTML content back.

Comment: In effect I also tried with JSON data but lot of post about this argument tells that is not necessary. The link you used is only for testing because the page url is [here](https://www.rinnovopatenticitylife.it/prenotazione-online/prenota.html)

Comment: You reference `DB_Query()` and `DB_Get_Results()` and these are common for Drupal CMS. That is why I asked that.

Comment: @Twisty I didn't know. I use these statements for a long time. Maybe I have copied it from some script in the past!.

Comment: @Twisty About giant payload response, if I change the headers to `content-type: application/json` in the ajax call and `data-type:"json"`, could change something? Because now load all tha html code + css + scripts

Comment: When you call `url: "prenotazione/prenota.php"` you're getting the whole page again. I would advise you create another PHP page that only gives you JSON data, like an API, instead of a the whole page again.

Comment: Yes but in this case I could send only the value of the date and not all other data. For example send value to a page `data.php` that collect only the date value and give back the JSON value to the `prenota.php` that populate itself. In theory! Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good scenario.

Comment: The answer I posted was designed for this type of scenario. Where it's a separate page, designed for just data.

Comment: I didn't understand. Thanks a lot. I'm starting to create a new page.

Comment: @Twist I'm almost at the end. Only one and hope last question: the file `data.php` must be included with `include('data.php');` in the main page, like my `prenota.php`?

Comment: No, the `data.php` would be stand alone. It may need to include an SQL Connection scripts, but otherwise it should not need to be included anyplace else since you're calling it via GET or POST.

Comment: Thanks. In fact now the `dataencode.php` (ex data.php)` encode an object on the server and the payload response is `{"giorno":"2019-01-18"}`. The date can change everytime I select a new date from a datepicker calendar. Now this value I would send to a sql query in php to refresh and update the hours table. Then everytime I choose a new date, the hours table could show me what hours are available and what not. The availability can change everyday. What is the route to follow?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, your PHP code is a bit dated and may be using older function. I would investigate using MySQLi function versus MySQL. It's also not clear where some of the PHP variable are define, like `$table21n` and `$table20n`. I would also consider configuring it like:

```
<?php
switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    case 'POST':
    post_handler();
    break;
    case 'GET':
    get_handler();
    break;
    default:
    other_handler();
    break;
}
$handler = array();
function post_handler() {
    $giornosel  = $_POST['giornosel'];
    $handler['method'] = "post";
    $handler['query'] = $giornosel;
}
function get_handler() {
    $giornosel  = $_GET['giornosel'];
    $handler['method'] = "get";
    $handler['query'] = $giornosel;
}
function other_handler() {
    $giornosel  = $_REQUEST['giornosel'];
    $handler['method'] = "request";
    $handler['query'] = $giornosel;
}
$data = array('handler' => $handler);
$data['elements'] = array();
// This first query populate the div of the enabled hour cells   
$query = DB_Query("SELECT * FROM $table21n WHERE enabled = '1' AND fascia ='1'  ORDER BY orario ASC");
while ($result = DB_Get_Results($query)){
    $div_id = $result[orario];
    // this second query check the hours in DB that are available or not with a simple count. If available, the radio button is displayed, otherwise not.
    $count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM $table20n WHERE orario = '$div_id' AND giorno = '$giornosel' ");
    $res_count = mysql_fetch_row($count);
    $totale = $res_count[0];
    if($totale >= $valore) {
        $disabled = "invisible"; // some css class
        $bgcolor = "BGoccupato";
    }
    else {
        $disabled = '';
        $bgcolor = 'BGlibero';
    }
    $conto = ($valore - $totale);
    $ore = substr($div_id, 0,2);
    $min =substr($div_id, 2,4);
    array_push($data['elements'], array(
        'tag' => "div",
        'attr' => arrray(
            'id' => $div_id,
            'class' => "centopercento $bgcolor"
        ),
        'content' => "$ore:$min</br>"
    ));
    array_push($data['elements'], array(
        'tag' => "input",
        'attr' => array(
            'type' => "radio",
            'id' => $div_id . "-input",
            'class' => "$disabled radiorario",
            'value' => $div_id,
            'name' => "orario"
        ),
        'appendTo' => "#" . $div_id
    ));
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

The idea with this code is that you can make an AJAX request to it and get back JSON data that is easier to work with in JavaScript. The expected result would be something like:

```
{
  "handler":{
    "method":"get",
    "query":"2019-01-18"
  },
  "elements":[{
    "tag":"div",
    "attr":{
      "id":"1122",
      "class":"centopercento BGoccupato"
    },
    "content":"11:22<\/br>"
  },{
    "tag":"input",
    "attr":{
      "type":"radio",
      "id":"1122-input",
      "class":"invisible radiorario",
      "value":"1122",
      "name":"orario"
    },
    "appendTo":"#1122"
  }]
}
```

You can then build the elements in jQuery like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "prenotazione/prenota.php",
  data: { giornosel: values },
  dataType:"json",
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    if(data.elememts.length){
      $.each(data.elements, function(i, el){
        var myEl = $("<" + el.tag + ">", el.attr);
        if(el.content != undefined){
          myEl.html(el.content);
        }
        if(el.appendTo != undefined){
          myEl.appendTo(el.appendTo);
        } else {
          myEl.appendTo($('#orariosel'));
        }
      });
    }
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("Ajax Error: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
  }
});
```

This way the AJAX will know to expect JSON data that can be populated in the `data` variable upon success. This will be treated like an Object type and can be easily iterated to build the needed tags.

Hope this helps clarify a few things.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. In order: the 2 variables `$table21n` and `$table20n` are defined by an inc file included on the page that is connected to the DB by a `DB_Connect()` statement on top of page before head tag.

Comment: The ajax call report an error: `Ajax Error: parsererror SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" prenota.html:563:7`. Line 563 is `console.log("Ajax Error: " + textStatus, errorThrown);` just before the close of the call. On html side I applied your structure based on arrays but doesn't load css styles and the `appendTo` elements. Now I'm trying to take a look about that

Comment: Only a question: the arrays structure what release of php needs? 5.6 is enough? Thanks

Comment: On the ajax call, at `if(el.appendTo != undefined){
          myEl.appendTo(el.appendTo);
        } else {
          myEl.appendTo($('#orariosel'));
        }`, if there isn't appendTo, I think it could be empty, like this `... } else {}`?

Comment: @Ric yes php 5.6 is fine. In regards to creating new elements, if you do not append the element to something, it is never added to the DOM and thus never added to the page. This if statement was created to attached the parent DIV to the proper location. I made a guess since it was not clear from your code example.